# Why is this parametric integral not continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, continuity, lebesgue-integral

Define $f(x, w) = x \exp(-(xw)²)$ and $g(x) = \int_\mathbb{R} f(x,w) d\lambda(w)$. It is easy to check that for $x > 0$ we have $g(x) = \sqrt{\pi}$ by using the substitution $t(w) = xw$ and arriving at the Gaussian distribution. Similarly we have $g(-x) = -\sqrt{\pi}$. Therefore, $g$ is not continuous at $x = 0$.

However, the map $w \mapsto f(x,w)$ is measurable for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, since it is continuous. Similarly, the map $x \mapsto f(x,w)$ is also continuous for all $w \in \mathbb{R}$, since it can be written as the composition of continuous maps. Thus it must be the case that there is no majorant $M \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ such that $|f(x,w)| \le M(w)$ for $\lambda$-almost all $w\in\mathbb{R}$. Otherwise, $g$ would also be continuous everywhere.

How can I show that such a majorant does not exist? I have tried the following:

Let $M \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ be a majorant for $w \mapsto f(x,w)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Therefore
$$|f(x,w)| \le |x| \exp(-(xw)^2) \le M(w)$$
For $w \in (-\frac{1}{x}, \frac{1}{x})$, we have $$|x| \exp(-(xw)^2) \le |x| \exp(-1) \xrightarrow[x \to \infty]{}\infty$$
showing that such an upper bound $M(w)$ cannot exist. However in this limiting process $(-\frac{1}{x}, \frac{1}{x})$ also goes to $\varnothing$, thus $M(w)$ would be a majorant almost everywhere. Where is the mistake in my reasoning? Thank you!

(EDIT: I think I can't choose $w \in (-\frac{1}{x}, \frac{1}{x})$ in this manner, since there is no fixed $x$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, there are no majorant such that $|f(x,w)|\leq M(w)$ for almost all $w\in\mathbb{R}$ and $M\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$, otherwise using the theorem giving the continuity of parametric integral gives that $g$ is continuous, which is false, so that already proves it.

If you still wanna see this another way, if we have, (almost everywhere) $$\forall x,w\in\mathbb{R},~~ |f(x,w)| = |x|e^{-(xw)^2}\leq M(w),$$ then evaluating that in $(x,w) = (z^{-1},z)$ for $z\ne0$ gives $$|z|^{-1} e^{-1}\leq M(z).$$ The left-side is not integrable on $[1,+\infty)$ but the right-side is by hypothesis, which is absurd.

Comment: This makes sense! Thank you.

Comment: No problem! Also I forgot to add, you're right about what you're doing being wrong. The only $w\in[-1/x,1/x]$ for all $x>0$ (since $x$ is not fixed) is $w=0$, so you showed $M(0) = \infty$ (which is not enough to be absurd).